# Connect light fixture to a junction box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a junction box where wires from 3 electric cables are connected together:

[image]

Is there a way I can hook up a light fixture to this box? The fixture looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you tell which of the two potential always-hots is an always-hot? (The answer could be both or neither, by the way.)  Also, what else is on this circuit?

Comment: 3 black wires joined together are hot. Red and white wires are cold. Do you mean I should disconnect 3 black wires and check whether each of them is hot?

Comment: I don't know what those cables are connected to -- they are in the basement, and run somewhere into the walls...

Comment: Is there a wall switch  that operates a light or outlet?  Or one that you don't know what it does?

Comment: There is a light switch in that room and it operates another light fixture there. It looks like it doesn't do anything to the wires in the junction box in question, since 3 connected black wires are always hot.

Comment: You said the red wires were cold... was the other light on when you tested the red wires?

Comment: I agree with jack red is usually a switched hot.

Comment: @Leo -- do you want this fixture to be operated by the wall switch or by the pull chain? Also, does turning the light switch on make the red wires in this box hot?

Comment: Are there ONE or TWO switches that control this light? (Or alternately, do nothing that you know of)?   Are there any switches that cause the red wires to go from cold to hot?  The presence of red wires means one of two things depending on if there are 1 or 2 controlling switches.

Comment: JACK -- two red wires appear to have low voltage each (12-48 V according to my contactless tester), regardless of the light switch position in that room. ThreePhaseEel -- I'll be ok with just the pull chain operation of the fixture. Harper -- There is only 1 light switch in that room, and it does not affect the low voltage in the red wires, the low voltage is always there.

Comment: @Leo are there smoke detectors on this circuit?

Comment: It's possible, but I'm not 100% sure. If that's the case, can I still follow Steve's answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you plan on using the pull chain.  If that’s the case I think you need a black wire from the fixture to the black marette and a white wire from the fixture to the white marette. If there is a terminal on the fixture for ground you would join it to the other grounds as well which I think have their own marette if I’m looking at that picture correctly. There are several experienced people involved with this conversation who you should consult with first, but I believe it’s the easy answer.